# Download ios application

Tags: ios, download

I have an IOS application that I want to download from a link existing in a web application. I have created a plist file containing the URL of the *"ipa"*. But when I click on the link from my iPhone, I get this message: "cannot connect to ...".

This is my plist file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software-package</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>https://blabla.fr:8443/test.ipa</string>
          </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
          <key>bundle-identifier</key>
          <string>com.mycompany.test</string>
          <key>bundle-version</key>
          <string>1.3</string>
          <key>kind</key>
          <string>software</string>
          <key>title</key>
          <string>test</string>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

My plist and ipa files are accessible from an URL on port 8443.

Comment: Sorry @Keith Edits got a bit jumbled there!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this it's help to You.

http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air

Comment: Hello,

thanks for your response.

But, it's exactly what I did to generate my plist file.

I think that I have a problem with my server config.

In fact, I have a proxy in my server configured on the port 8443. The proxy call apache on the 8080 port. So, there are an automatic 304 redirection to call my files (plist and ipa).

It's possible that it's the problem